# Why can't I define float before scanf (in this case)?

Tags: c

I am a beginner to coding trying to learn C. I tried to make a program which would convert celsius to fahrenheit. When I tried to run this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Define celsius and fahrenheit.
    float celsius;
    float far = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;

    // Ask for Celsius temperature
    printf("What is the temperature in celsius?\n");

    // Get the input of the temperature
    scanf("%f", &celsius);

    // Convert to Fahrenheit

    //Print the temperature in Farenheit.
    printf("The temperature converted to Farenheit is %f\n", far);

    return 0;
}
```

It gives the output (no error / warning):

```
What is the temperature in celsius?
5
The temperature converted to Farenheit is -1172181139767515960282508306484822016.000000
```

Which is wrong as it should be 41. Also, every time I run this, I get a different temperature.

However, running this code (defining far after scanf), there are no issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // Define celsius
    float celsius;

    // Ask for Celsius temperature
    printf("What is the temperature in celsius?\n");

    // Get the input of the temperature
    scanf("%f", &celsius);
    
    // Convert to Fahrenheit
    float far = (celsius * 9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0;

    //Print the temperature in Farenheit.
    printf("The temperature converted to Farenheit is %f\n", far);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
What is the temperature in celsius?
5
The temperature converted to Farenheit is 41.000000
```

Why is it so?

PS - Did I take a right decision by choosing C first? I chose C because I'd heard it makes a good foundation for other languages and also because I like Linux.

Comment: `float far = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;` utilizes the value fo `celsius` (which is indeterminate in your code) at the time the expression is evaluated. In the first code list if you're expecting `far` to magically change later when you change the value of `celsius` that isn't how the language works. The second code fixes this by calculating the value being assigned to `far` *after* `celsius` is determined.

Comment: Sentences are executed in sequence, so you cannot apply your operation prior to reading the input data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case

```
 float celsius;
 float far = (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
```

you're using `celsius` uninitialized. It's an automatic storage local scope variable, and unless initialized explicitly, contains indeterminate value.

If not anything, the result will be indeterminate.

However, once you store some value in `celsius`, and then use it, the proper value will be used and result will be as per expectation.

Answer (score 0):

What else do you expect by the first code.

It's obvious that it will show you some or the other garbage value since the value of celcius is not initialized.

After scanf(), it is initialized so then it works fine.
The other code is absolutely fine.

Kindly use that one